# UITabBar disappears after pushed to new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `UITabBarController` that has 3 buttons. The second button points to `ViewController1` which is connected to another view called `ViewController2`. After I tap a button in `ViewController2` I programmatically present `ViewController1` again, that works perfect except one thing. After I "arrived" to `ViewController1` the tab bar disappears.

I'm using this method to navigate back to `ViewController1`. (exactly I navigate to its navigation controller, but already tried with the view)

```
- (void)presentViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstViewNavigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination"];
    [self presentViewController:firstViewNavigationController animated:animated completion:nil];     
}
```

I call here the first method

```
- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];

    [self presentViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This method hides the tab bar in the `ViewController2`, I already tried without it, therefore there is no problem with it.

```
-(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    return YES;
}
```

I can't figure out why this thing happens, I think it's a fair solution, that worked well for a several times when I needed to present views. I've read it can happen with segues, but I'm doing it with code without segues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your code works right. There should not be tab bar when you present FirstViewController from SecondViewController. Because when you call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` its basically creates a new instance of that view controller, and of course, there is no tab bar.

The right way to go back to your first view controller is to pop SecondViewController (or dismiss it, if it presented modally). So your final code should be like this

```
- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    // If this view controller (i.e. SecondViewController) was pushed, like in your case, then       
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // If this view controller was presented modally, then
    // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And of course, your view controller hierarchy in storyboard must be like this:

```
                                                 
                        -- UINavigationController -> FirstViewController -> SecondViewController
                        | 
->UITabBarController____|
                        -...
                        -...
```

Comment: It's working fine, thank you very much. I can award the bounty only after 23 hours (don't know why), but tomorrow I'll do it.

Comment: You're Welcome. 
As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty  
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the same and got the same result.

My solution was simple, on the push do this :

```
UINavigationController *firstViewNavigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destination"];

firstViewNavigationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true; // Insert this and set it to what you want to do

[self presentViewController:firstViewNavigationController animated:animated completion:nil];
```

and then remove your

```
-(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried with true and false. Only the true value affected one thing, it showed the tab bar in ViewController2.

Comment: the very strange as I just tried in both scenarios on blank code (I admit I don't use storyboards) and it worked fine.  Did you remove the hidesbottombarwhenpushed from your code ? , if so maybe it is pulling in something from the storyboard.

Comment: I'm using storyboard. I think i will try to navigate to the second button of the tab bar instead of a view controller.